# Can I pass a generic type parameter in a static generic method using a params object?

Tags: java, generics, lombok, generic-type-parameters

I'm refactoring a generic method which has been overloaded many times to reduce the overloads. I've removed all overloads leaving only one method, opting instead to use a single params object encapsulating all parameters passed to the overloaded methods.

Is it possible to encapsulate the `Supplier<T> func` inside `CompleteParams params` for `complete(CompleteParams params)` whilst preserving the semantics of `complete(Supplier<T> func, String param1, boolean param2)`?

I'm not sure this is possible from what I've read in the [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html?fbclid=IwAR0XmxGISzV9ewg8_ALgggSrShMjocwhsb-3JIKVgLT4K1k14QUbC_4bnkA)

> Generic methods are methods that introduce their own type parameters. This is similar to declaring a generic type, but the type parameter's scope is limited to the method where it is declared.

Previous code:

```
// multiple overloads
public static <T> T complete(Supplier<T> func, String param1) {
    complete(func, null);
}

//original
public static <T> T complete(Supplier<T> func, String param1, boolean param2) {
    final T = func.get();
}
```

Current code:

```
public static <T> complete(CompleteParams params) {
    final T = params.getFn().get();
}
```

CompleteParams.java

```
@Value
@Builder
public class CompleteParams {
    Supplier func;
    String param1;
    Boolean param2;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234538/discussion-on-question-by-mrrain-can-i-pass-a-generic-type-parameter-in-a-static).

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside that this is a terrible idea altogether (see my comment above, and sorry again =/), you want to parametrize your parameters class:

```
public class CompleteParams<T> {
    Supplier<T> func;
    String param1;
    Boolean param2;
}

public static <T> complete(CompleteParams<T> params) {
    final T = params.func.get();
}
```

Notice that the language "type parameter's scope is limited to the method where it is declared" doesn't mean that you can't use the a type variable in one scope as an argument to another type!  Generics would not be very useful if this were the case...

(I'm not sure what your anotations (ie. `@Builder`) are doing there or what library they are part of.  Is that Spring?  Lombok?   You may need to design in specific ways to satisfy whatever contracts they imply, as well...)

[edit:  Ok, you've edited the question to indicate this is in fact Lombok.  My proposed solution will work fine with Lombok's `@Builder`, so game on.   But, check out the readability mess, stack trace fat, and performance hit that happens for every call now when you do something like `WhateverClassItIs.complete(CompleteParams.<TYPE>.builder().param1("foo")....)`.  Do you think writing this every call is really cleaner than invoking the old overloaded methods?]

Comment: Actually, another way to approach this which might be a little saner is to use a fluent pattern on a new sort of stateful operation object: `WhateverClassCompletion.newCompletion().param1().func(someSupplier).complete()`.  You could then do the "parameter logic" and *delegate* to existing overloaded complete()....